# Format time output within template using Pelican

Tags: python, python-2.7, pelican

I am using this package: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pelican-next-meetup/0.1.1

I have successfully installed the package and I can fetch data from meetup.com

Here is a snippet of my index.html file:

```
<h2 class="text-center">
  <a href="{{ next_meetup.url }}">Link to meetup</a>
  <p>{{ next_meetup.time }}</p>
</h2>
```

The problem I have is that the time displays like this: 1471449600000

That timestamp = 17 August 2016 6.00PM (roughly)

I have managed to convert that time to a datetime in the following file called timecon.py:

```
import datetime
import time

timestamp = 1471449600000

date_display = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp/1000)
```

However, trying to make this file work (or even run on its own) doesn't work.

(The file won't run if I make `timestamp = next_meetup.time`)

How can I convert the `next_meetup.time` into a datetime so that I can display a formatted date and time of the next meetup on my Pelican blog?

**EDIT**

I tried to integrate the functionality of `timecon.py` into my `pelicanconf.py` file using an import like this:

```
# some other code
from name_meetup
# some other code
#
DATE_DISPLAY = name_meetup.time
```

But that doesn't even work, cause I get this error:

```
from next_meetup
               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

**EDIT 2**

I also tried all of these and none worked:

```
from next_meetup import get_next_meetup
from next_meetup import next_meetup
```

Comment: You haven't completed your import. It should be `from next_meetup import something`

Comment: @Andy even when I say `from next_meetup import all` it doesn't work. same goes for `next_meetup import next_meetup`